# Enable a div based on the response from an ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have an ajax call and i need to show one particular div based on the response from the ajax call.   here is my ajax call

```
               var cmnumber = document.forms['myform']['cm'].value;
        alert(cmnumber)
    $.ajax({
    type:'get',
    url: "/validatecm/"+cmnumber,
    cache:false,
    async:true,
    data:cmnumber,
    success: function(data) {

    },
    error: function(data) {
    }
    })

    });
```

I need to show on div if the response is success. Default the div is Hidden.

```
                    <div class="downtime" id="downtime" style="display: none" >
                          --------------
                    </div>
```

Any help wil be appreciated..

Comment: what is the success condition? ie what value will be returned by the server if the request is success

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var cmnumber = document.forms['myform']['cm'].value;
    alert(cmnumber)
    $.ajax({
      type:'get',
      url: "/validatecm/"+cmnumber,
      cache:false,
      async:true,
      data:cmnumber,
     success: function(data) {

       if(data == "success")
        $('#downtime').show();
       else
        $('#downtime').hide();

   },
  error: function(data) {
   }
})
```

Comment: please mark it as answer if you got the solution with this answer:)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

```
$.ajax({
    type:'get',
    url: "/validatecm/"+cmnumber,
    cache:false,
    async:true,
    data:cmnumber
}).done(function(data){
    $('#downtime').show();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `data` into the `div` and show it.

```
success: function(data) {
  $('#downtime').html(data).show();
},
error: function(data) {
  $('#downtime').html().hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("downtime").style.display = "block";
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/display

Answer (score 0):

get the value of text box and save it in cmnumber. Make sure you include jquery in your html file

```
function makeAjaxCall(){

    var cmnumber=$("#cm").val();

    var url="/validatecm/"+cmnumber;

    $.ajax({url:url,success:function(result){

        handleResult(result);

    }});

}

function handleResult(result){
// if result is what you expect it is then enable the div

    if(result=="ok"){

        $("#downtime").css('display','block');

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to AJAX but you have to change one thing to hide/show a the div:

```
var cmnumber = document.forms['myform']['cm'].value;
    alert(cmnumber)
    $.ajax({
      type:'get',
      url: "/validatecm/"+cmnumber,
      cache:false,
      async:true,
      data:cmnumber,
     success: function(data) {

       if(data.**MESSAGE** == "success")
        $('#downtime').show();
       else
        $('#downtime').hide();

   },   error: function(data) {    } })
```